# What am I? Animal edition

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, wordplay, knowledge, computer-puzzle

> I reveal hidden secrets, where nanoscale put me there. 
>   I exist in a honker -- Maybe a carapace too. 
>   What am I?

Hint:

> Maybe I'm not *quite* an animal.

Hint 2:

> Bourne Again Carapace

Hint 3:

> A honker is an animal that is known for honking -- NOT a nose.

Comment: Somewhere in between, then?

Comment: Alright, I think it may have been a bit difficult. I've added another hint and a few tags.

Comment: If no-one answers this by tomorrow, I think that would be a good time for me to post my intended answer (June 10th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it's probably time I post the actual answer to this. I would like to note though that many of the answers that other people posted seem just as valid as this one:

What am I?

> A cat, as in the bash command to print the contents of a file.
>  Meow

I reveal hidden secrets,

> The cat command can reveal what is in a file.

Where nanoscale put me there.

> "nanoscale" is a play on words from the command "nano," which can be used to create text files.

I exist in a honker

> [A honker can be a penguin,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG4le02fLBo) which is the Linux mascot. The cat command can be used on Linux.

-- Maybe a carapace too.

> Carapace means shell, and the cat command can be implemented directly in a shell rather than a separate executable.

Hint 1:

> Maybe I'm not *quite* an animal.
>  The answer is a shell command -- not a literal animal.

Hint 2:

> Bourne Again Carapace -> Bourne Again Shell -> [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Hint 3:

> A honker is an animal that is known for honking -- NOT a nose.
>  A penguin isn't a nose, [and it is known for honking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG4le02fLBo).

Comment: Oh man, I went with the first honker animal I found and never thought to check for other versions, even though (or maybe because) I had trouble googling it in the first place.

Comment: Also, instead of half of the hints being about animals and half about computers, it was all about computers.

Comment: @snetch the large number of animal hints is a bit of a red herring, but, the "computer-puzzle" tag does fairly clearly state that it is computer related.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> DNA?

I reveal hidden secrets

> DNA provides genetic information

where nanoscale put me there

> The diameter of a DNA molecule is about 2 nanometers

I exist in a honker -- Maybe a carapace too.

> DNA forms everything, from honkers to carapaces

Comment: What's a honker?

Comment: @RipTide  I think it's a nose.

Comment: Nope. This isn't it. I think it's a good answer though. Please see the hint and tags I have added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Going laterally here...

> A snail!

I reveal hidden secrets

> The  [snail gene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNAI1) is crucial for the embryonic stage.
>  And those genes have potentially the information of the whole cellular structure of the person? (I am not a scientist... :-))

where nanoscale put me there

> need a nanoscale to measure the gene...

I exist in a honker -- Maybe a carapace too.

> Referring to snot and a snail.
>  EXPLANATION:
>  A nose is called a 'honker' - for readily apparent reasons.
>  And a snail lives in a caparace, a 'shell'. (To put it non-delicately: snot and the slug part of the snail look pretty much the same...)

On the hint:

> People don't look at slugs (the slimy part of the snail) as an *animal* per se. Because they seemingly grow out of nothing when it rains...
>
>  Oh, I don't know!!! Went way too far on this I think... :oP

Comment: Nope. This isn't it. I think it's a good answer though. Please see the hint and tags I have added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

What am I?

> Root

I exist in a honker -- Maybe a carapace too.

> honker=goose (hint 3), carapace=Bash (hint 2). Geese probably eat roots, and in Bash you can become root.

I reveal hidden secrets, where nanoscale put me there.

> Root can access all files and run anything, and it's a software construct so it can't be seen unless you look at some tiny nanometers of the hard drive.

Comment: This is a bit closer, good job, but it isn't quite it. The answer is a bit more of an animal than a root is.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A bug

I reveal hidden secrets, where nanoscale put me there.

> a bug in a computer program can reveal hidden secrets about the code sometimes maybe?  a bug is small/nano creature?

I exist in a honker -- Maybe a carapace too.

> A bug could be eaten by a goose and there are bugs in Bash?
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)

Hint:
Maybe I'm not quite an animal.

> a bug can be an animal but it can also be an unwanted feature in software?

Hint 2:
Bourne Again Carapace

> Bourne Again Shell (Bash)?

Comment: Unfortunatley, no this isn't what I was going for. Perhaps I made this a bit difficult.

Comment: You certainly did but you won't here me complaining.

Comment: I was gonna post this, after I posted my latest answer, but it seemed too similar/close to mine, and someone would have posted it anyway and it would have still been wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Fish (Friendly Interactive Shell)

I reveal hidden secrets, where nanoscale put me there.

> FISH will show helpful hints as you type the commands

I exist in a honker -- Maybe a carapace too.

> Geese eat fish, and the shell part should be self-explanitority

Comment: Nope, not quite. I think I made this too difficult and left too much room for alternative valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but the hint gave me a clue
Are you

> A virus

Comment: Nope. It is something both much closer and much further from being an actual, literal animal. I'm being a bit metaphorical -- it isn't close to an animal in the scientific sense, but rather in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: I read nanoscale and The hint. I'm more science...

Comment: This very nonscientific. Also, I did leave a tag out that would be relevant but I thought would make it too easy. I guess I could also mention that there is a bit of technology relevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> nanobot? They can make up all kind of things from nanobots, including carapaces and potentially things you can honk with.

Comment: Nope. I think it's a reasonable answer though. Please see the hint and tags I have added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for this is:

> Genes

Comment: This isn't it. I can't give any assistance though because you didn't include how you got to it. I can say though that you're thinking a bit literally.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to be:

> A mushroom?